# R Shiny: update text without updating the datatable

Tags: r, shiny

My R Shiny app has text and a datatable.  When I click a datatable row, the data changes and the table is updated using a datatable proxy so that the table page doesn't change.  Also the text updates to show how many rows were clicked.

The problem is that when the text updates, it also updates the table which resets to page 1, ruining the point of using the datatable proxy.

Here is a working example.  Run it with and without the last code line commented (the code line starting with `v$selected_count <- ...`)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("app_ui")
    )    
  , server = function(input, output){

    v <- reactiveValues(
      selected_count = 0
      , data = iris
    )

    output$app_ui <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        h5(v$selected_count)  # Want this to update without affecting the datatable
        , DTOutput('tbl')
      )
    })

    output$tbl = renderDT({
      datatable(iris)
      })

    observeEvent(
      input$tbl_rows_selected
      , {
        i <- input$tbl_rows_selected
        v$data[i, "Species"] <- ""

        dataTableProxy("tbl") %>% replaceData(v$data, resetPaging = FALSE, clearSelection = FALSE)

        v$selected_count <- v$selected_count + 1 # Comment this line to see the difference to the datatable
      }
    )      

  }
)
```

Comment: Why don't you put the `DTOutput` in the UI, instead of the `renderUI` ?

Comment: I know what you mean however the example is based on a large app and all the UI components are in the server, the text and table are inside a dropdown inside the server code.  It might be worth sticking it in a module however I'd prefer to keep it simple as possible.